# set ngStyle using Angular2

Tags: css, angular

I have a component in which I establish in ngStyle through a function, It works all styles except for overflow-y, I do not know if it actually sets itself well Any ideas?

```
  onChangeFilterClientes(obj:any):any[]{        
    return this.clientes.filter(c => c.Nombre.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(obj.query)>-1);        

  }
```

The functions on my component:

```
interface IOpcionesListaAutocomplete {
    width: number;
    height: number; 
    isOverflowY: boolean;
}

export class OpcionesListaAutocomplete implements IOpcionesListaAutocomplete {
    width: number;
    height: number; 
    isOverflowY: boolean;
    constructor()  { }
}

@Input()
opcionesLista: IOpcionesListaAutocomplete = {
    width: 550,
    height: 150,
    isOverflowY: true
};


addStylesLista(){  
    let styles= { 
      'heigth.px':this.opcionesLista.height,
      'width.px':this.opcionesLista.width,
      'overflow-y': this.opcionesLista.isOverflowY? 'auto': 'hidden'
    };
    return styles;
}
```

All styles works ok, except overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a space between the question mark and the variable.

```
  'overflow-y': this.opcionesLista.isOverflowY ? 'auto': 'hidden'
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Legman's answer, noticed another typo in the `addStylesLista()` method for `'height.px'` (in the question it is `'heigth.px'`).

Answer (score 0):

It is probably overridden due to a style specification somewhere else? Try adding `!important` to it:

```
'overflow-y': (this.opcionesLista.isOverflowY? 'auto': 'hidden') + ' !important'
```